# SSIS sysssislog missing event "FileNameChanged"

Tags: sql, visual-studio-2010, logging, ssis, visual-studio-2005

My company just upgraded from SSIS 2005 to 2010. This changes the log table from sysdtslog90 to sysssislog. We noticed the same packages were no longer logging records to the new sysssislog table with event name "FileNameChanged" which we were using for reporting. Our end goal is to know the file name that the package connected to in certain tasks.

Has anyone experienced this? I am not seeing this "event name" in the logging configuration in either version 2005 or 2010.

Comment: Did you create a custom EventHandler for `FileNameChanged` or do you handle this within the existing Event handler framework?

Comment: Just so you know - there is no SSIS 2010. Both SQL Server Integration Services (SQL 2008), and SQL Server Data Tools (SQL 2012) have the sysssislog table when you use the SQL Server logging provider.

Comment: Sorry, we are using Visual Studio 2010. Is there a way to create custom EventHandlers?